# MalformedMessageException: Invalid LF found in token

Tags: websphere

when i call my local application dployed in was 7 i receive the following message at console:

```
00000053 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: Emesso evento FFDC in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_2540254_15.11.19_12.04.22.6095127841027186654491.txt HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation 2
```

On file at ffdc the error is:

```
[19/11/15 12.04.22:610 CET]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.wsspi.genericbnf.exception.MalformedMessageException SourceId:HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation ProbeId:2 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink@40ed40ed
com.ibm.wsspi.genericbnf.exception.MalformedMessageException: Invalid LF found in token
    at com.ibm.ws.genericbnf.impl.BNFHeadersImpl.findTokenLength(BNFHeadersImpl.java:4551)
    at com.ibm.ws.genericbnf.impl.BNFHeadersImpl.parseTokenExtract(BNFHeadersImpl.java:4995)
    at com.ibm.ws.genericbnf.impl.GenericMessageImpl.parseLine(GenericMessageImpl.java:212)
    at com.ibm.ws.genericbnf.impl.GenericMessageImpl.parseMessage(GenericMessageImpl.java:348)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpBaseMessageImpl.parseMessage(HttpBaseMessageImpl.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.parseMessage(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:345)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:295)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)

==> Performing default dump from com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HTTPChannelDM :Thu Nov 19 12:04:22 CET 2015
+Data for directive [defaulthttpchannel] obtained.:
==> Dump complete for com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HTTPChannelDM :Thu Nov 19 12:04:22 CET 2015
```

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: What do you mean by "call"?  It looks like there was an erroneous \n in your request headers.

Comment: i call the url of my application, the front end are develop in flex and back end are j2ee.

Comment: What specifically are you using to make the "call"?  Are you opening a socket and writing the request directly?  Are you using a browser/XMLHttpRequest?  Are you using URL.openConnection, Apache HttpClient, or JAX-RS client?  Are you using JAX-WS or some other high-level client?  What headers are you specifying in the request?  Have you tried inspecting the request via wireshark or other network inspection?